# how to create a table with git tags name, annotation and date

Tags: git, tags

I recently created a Github workflow to automatically update a changelog file on new releases

I would like now to put in the changelog all git tag annotations without manually type

`git show <tagname>`

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273531/how-to-sort-git-tags-by-version-string-order-of-form-rc-x-y-z-w/22634649#22634649) I get with
`git tag --sort=-v:refname -n -l "${1}*"`

a table with 2 columns: tag name and tag annotation.
I wonder if it is possible to add also the date.

any idea how to do it?

Comment: `git for-each-ref` is the tool for this. Use a [`format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names) to get whatever info and output style you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26563410/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22for-each-ref%22+tags